# For every word in textfile add a timer for each word vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program to keep track of Timers in a game. The game has chat and you can say "/note blah t". This will save "blah t" to a textfile in the gamefolder. I need to be able to see what the user added to the file, I am thinking about doing text.contains but I need to recover the entire line of the .contains. And when I receive the line I need to read the line, and make a new timer (time determined by what was entered for "t") that adds a label to a form with the time plus what was entered for "blah", here is my code so far.

NOTE the I am mainly concerned with the Timer1 code, all other code is just to prevent user from clicking on my form when in game.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" Alias "GetForegroundWindow" () As IntPtr
    Private Declare Auto Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByVal lpString As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal cch As Integer) As Integer
    Private makel As String
    Private InitialStyle As Integer
    Dim PercentVisible As Decimal
    Dim Lea

    Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
        InitialStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20)
        PercentVisible = 0.1

        SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, -20, InitialStyle Or &H80000 Or &H20)

        'SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * PercentVisible, &H2)

        'Me.BackColor = Color.Red
        Me.TopMost = True
    End Sub

    Private Function GetCaption() As String
        Dim Caption As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
        GetWindowText(hWnd, Caption, Caption.Capacity)
        Return Caption.ToString()
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function GetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")> Public Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetLayeredWindowAttributes")> Public Shared Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal crKey As Integer, ByVal alpha As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim CapTxt As String = GetCaption()
        Dim Path As String = "C:\Riot Games\League Of Legends\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\0.0.1.123\MyNotes.txt"
        If CapTxt = "League of Legends (TM) Client" Then
            Me.TopMost = True
            Try
                Test.Text = File.ReadAllLines(Path).FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Contains("Ezreal"))

                ''System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path, "")
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Else
                Me.TopMost = False
            Me.SendToBack()
        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Other than your explanation being very hard to follow, I can think that users would not like having something like a key logger monitoring what they type. What is it exactly you're trying to achieve? Please explain the problem you're trying to solve, not how you think it should be solved.

Comment: @LucMorin When playing a game, the user can type "/note <thepersonthereplaying> <theabilitytheyused>" and this would add a note in there notes text file. The text file DIRECTORY never changes. I want to be able to make a timer for every time the person adds a new line to the text file.

Comment: Ok. I see. So you need to monitor changes to that file, then parse it to find specific text and start a corresponding timer. You only mention displaying the time left for those timers, but do you also need something to be "triggered" by the timer? You mention a `TextBox`, but since timers can be added/removed dynamically, you'll need a GUI that can react to those timers being added/removed. Please edit your question and provide as much information as possible, but also please share whatever code you already have.

Comment: @LucMorin kk I will try to re explain, and include my code. Sorry I am really bad at explaining :(

Comment: Well, put yourself in our position. If you can't explain the problem well, it'll be very hard for us to help ;-)

Comment: @LucMorin take a look at it now :)

Comment: Well, I do understand what you're trying to achieve now, but your current approach is flawed, and I'd need to write the whole thing for you, which I don't really feel like doing now. You'll need a `FileSystemWatcher` to monitor the file, then when it's changed, you'll need to read it, find the line with the "timer" command, compare with a list of already running/ellapsed timers (to make sure not to repeat the same timer twice), then create a new Timer object (and associated GUI controls). It's not really all that complicated, you just need to think it through ;-)

Comment: @LucMorin Thanks! Can you give me some quick code like for every blah create new blah? This is where i seem to go blank at, as I can only think of creating a new label, but how would I handle names (to make sure there not the same)